# Line equation and distance between a line and a point in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I've looked for many similar questions but could not find an answer that helps.

I have a point $p$ $(x,y,z)$ on a plane, and a normal to the plane $n$ $(a,b,c)$. I need to find the equation of a line defined by the point $p$ and normal $n$.

Then I would like to know how to find the distance from any arbitrary point $p_a$ $(x_a,y_a,z_a)$ and the line defined above.

Comment: @Abramo NO, outside the plane

Comment: "..a line defined by $\;p\;$ and the normal $\;n\;$" ? There shall be infinite such lines...

Comment: But I know the point $ p $.

Comment: It doesn't matter, @SalamKh :I'm assuming you know both the normal and the point. Still, there are infinite lines that can be traced from that point through (some point of) that line.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand your issue here.

Comment: given one point and one line not through the point (in 2 or 3 dimensional space) , there is an infinite number of lines through the point and a point of the line. This is what I understand when you write "A line defined by a point and a (normal) line". Just do a little drawing.

Comment: isn't this the case all the time? even if there are infinite number of lines what stops me from getting an equation?

Comment: Nothing at all stops you: you even have infinite choices...:)

Comment: By a line defined by the point $p$ and normal $n$ do you mean _the_ line through $p$ parallel to $n$ ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line through a point $p$ which is parallel to the plane normal $n$ (or in other words - the line through a point $p$ normal to the plane with  normal $n$) is simply:

$${\bf p} + {\bf n} \cdot t$$
Where $t$ is the line parameter. To find the distance between a third point $q$ and this line, you may want to use the following formula:

$$d = \left|({\bf q}-{\bf p})\times({\bf q}-{\bf p}-{\bf{n}}/|{\bf n}|)\right|$$
Where $\times$ is the cross product.

Comment: Yes, and then what about the distance between any other point and this line?

Comment: @SalamKh - this should answer your question.

Comment: the second part of the distance equation, is it supposed to be $((q-p-n)/|n|)$ or $(q-p-(n/|n|))$ ?

Comment: @SalamKh - option two. that is only meaning possible given the precedence division has over subtraction.

Comment: I know that, I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something. sry.